# Interest Calculation on Savings Account

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, finance

I am trying to find interest on a savings account for the following transactions in an mvc.net application:

```
Date          Balance
-----------   -------
01-Apr-2011    100
05-Apr-2011    200
30-Apr-2011    300
28-Jun-2011    400
```

The interest rate is 4% per annum.

Is there a simple way to calculate simple interest for these transactions for the quarter (i.e. 01-Apr-2011 - 31-Jun-2011)?  Once I figure it out the calculation for one account, I will write a function to calculate it for all accounts.  I got the Average Daily Available Balance(ADAB) as 24500 / 91 = $269.23.  I used the below formula to get the simple interest for the quarter.  Is it correct?  Is there any other method to calculate the interest without using ADAB?

```
ADAB x (annual interest / 365 x number of days), or 269.23 x (0.04 / 365 x 91) = 2.6849
```

Comment: Please re-check your ADAB calculation.  The ADAB exceeds the highest daily balance listed in your example.

Comment: I just noticed and corrected it.  Thank you!

Comment: I'm not too sure I understand... Are you trying to compute compound interests? If so, you'd have a power somewhere.

Comment: Perhaps look at the standard [compound interest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest) formulas. Shouldn't need ADAB or whatever it is. It's like a really easy bit of math a junior in Econ 101 can do :p

Comment: Can you tell me how you would calculate the simple interest for the above transactions without ADAB?  Thank you!

Comment: Corrected. This is an example, not real data. It was a typo. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, neither calculation is correct.  First, 4% interest should be expressed as 0.04.  Next, the simple interest calculation should be ADAB x (annual interest / 365 x number of days), or 269.23 x (0.04 / 365 x 91) = 2.6849.

Because this is 4% simple interest for one quarter, if your answer is not roughly 1%, there is a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I got the same result in the second formula. I used interest rate as 4/100 instead of 0.04. Can you check again and tell me why the second calcuation is wrong?

Comment: The second calculation returns the correct result, but it is not self-evident how the calculation is structured. This is picking at nits, but if another developer looks at your calculation #2, that developer will not be able to see how the calculation is derived, in order to determine whether or not the calculation will return the correct result. That 100 hanging around at the end of the calculation creates confusion.

Comment: I used the same formula.  I just corrected the structure to make it more readable.  Thanks again!